Vue2 webpack splitChunks wrong path
I have a Vue 2 UI library that I use in my main project as a dependency from node_modules. Since this library is becoming larger and larger, I decided to implement code splitting. This way, I don't have to load all the parts at once, but only as I need them. Here is my webpack configuration:
  output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      library: 'myUI',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      umdNamedDefine: true, 
      publicPath: "auto",
      assetModuleFilename: 'src/[hash][ext][query]',
    },
splitChunks: {
            minSize: 10000,
            maxSize: 250000,
          cacheGroups: {
            dayjsLocales: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](dayjs)[\\/]locale[\\/]/,
              name: (module) => {
                const moduleFileName = module.identifier().split('/').reduceRight(item => item);

                return `dayjs-locales/${moduleFileName}`;
              },
              chunks: 'async',
              enforce: true,
            },
          },
        }

When I run a production build, in the dist folder, I have the main.js file and a dayjs-locales folder containing all the locales. When loading this main.js file in the main app, it is loaded correctly at https://localhost:8080/js/node_modules_my_ui_dist_main_js.js. However, when it tries to load the language, the path is incorrect: https://localhost:8080/js/js/dayjs-locales/cs.js.09e7592c1c8e67f185da.js.
any idea how to solve this issue? Thank you
I attempted to change the publicPath or chunkFilename, but it did not resolve the issue.

Have you tried with dayjs-locales_${moduleFileName} instead of dayjs-locales/${moduleFileName} ?

I just tried it now; however, the result is the same. I get a 404 error on the dayjs dependency, Here is how my library is beeing loaded and dayjs language Is here ... I don't know why the main file is loaded from "js/node_modules_sharry-europe_sharry-ui_dist," but dayjs is loaded from "js/fileName."

hm, then can you try with return moduleFileName; without a folder name ?

Now the path is /js/cs.js.c563ab4a1d093f060348.js but I still get 404 :/
